# Who are the Moyers in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

At first I wasn't sure if October 6 said Dinner with the "Mayors" or Dinner with the "Moyars", but after exiting the vault and being able to crouch, looking closer I could tell that the writer of the memo has a pronounced difference between their "a" and their "o" (see October 4's memo, the second word, "handy"), concluding that the entry is certainly "Moyers".

However, I can't find a single reference to them at all on the internet, nor have I found any relevant terminal entries so far (though there are a lot to go through). Do they even exist beyond this scribble?

[image: Calendar in Fallout 4]
[image: Closeup of Calendar]

Note: I started looking into this because the Sole Survivor's neighbors, with whom the SS may or may not had friendships, are named, have wiki pages, and some even make appearances later in the game. In contrast, the Moyers, despite having a rather apparent connection to the SS, essentially seem to not exist. Who are they?

Comment: They could be friends from a different town/suburb, rather than neighbours

Comment: Definitely. I mistakenly implied that I thought they lived in the neighborhood, but I figured they were from a different one, else they would be either among the vault victims or among the neighbors that appear later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By increasing the contrast, we can see that the name is actually "Mayers" or "Moyers":

[image: Screenshot with increased brightness]

Considering that Fallout 4 is set 210 years later, that Vault 111 was the only Vault we know of that experimented on cryogenic sleep, and that you're the only survivor of Vault 111 (aside from Shaun, your child), it's highly likely that the Mayers/Moyers probably either died long before Fallout 4 started (ignoring the introduction 210 years ago) or have since become Ghouls.

With that in mind, I've been searching for both names, and nothing came up. The only match I got was a ["Meyers" from New Vegas](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Meyers), but this is clearly neither the same person nor the same name.

Thus I believe the evidence (or lack thereof) indicates that the Mayers/Moyers probably never existed aside from that one note.

Comment: Thank you for your research! I definitely agree they are either dead or ghoulified--I was just hoping for a little more info along the lines of what we find out about the late Mr. Russell - just a little blurb about his purchase of chems for potentially more nefarious purposes. Also, just a friendly heads up: if someone does manage to find such info, I may have to change my accepted answer; otherwise, you get the green check! Thanks again for your research efforts!

Comment: @WiZΔRD, definitely feel free to change the accepted answer if a better answer appears in the future.